# Pass integer to activity from within handler

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an App in which an Activity is shown for 3 seconds, after which the next Activity is started. I succeeded with the following code:

```
// shows the picture for 3 seconds, then takes the user to GamePlay 
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ShowImage.this, GamePlay.class);

            ShowImage.this.startActivity(intent);
            ShowImage.this.finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
```

This Activity also shows a picture and I want to pass the ID of the picture to the next activity. I know it can be done (from experience, in another Activity) by using the following code (I tried inserting it in the blank line above):

```
this.putExtra("id", selected_image);
```

However, I get the error "the Method putExtra(String, int) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}"

**My question then is**, how do I pass the image-id to the next activity, while containing my 3-seconds delay?

Here is the rest of the Activity's code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShowImage extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_image, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // shows the activity
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // get the selected image id and crop the image
    final int selected_image = (Integer) intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
    Bitmap [] croppedBitmap = CreateBitmap.createBitmap(this, selected_image, 3);

        // create GridView for pictures to be showed in
        GridView grid_layout =  (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

        // pass the array with pieces to the image adapter
        grid_layout.setAdapter(new CroppedImageAdapter(this, croppedBitmap));

        // test text
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(selected_image), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // shows the picture for 3 seconds, then takes the user to GamePlay 
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ShowImage.this, GamePlay.class);
            this.putExtra("id", selected_image);
            ShowImage.this.startActivity(intent);
            ShowImage.this.finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
  this.putExtra("id", selected_image);
```

to

```
  intent.putExtra("id", selected_image);
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Could you maybe explain to me why and what I did wrong?

Comment: you can pass value from one activity to another by add putExtra with Intent object. You cannnot do it with "this". "this" reference to current class. Hope this answer is helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
intent.putExtra("id", selected_image);
```

Instead of :

```
this.putExtra("id", selected_image);
```

**Note :** in your code **this** is reference of handler and you pass intent data using **intent** reference not **this** reference.